# JQuery Change Class Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have try to create "expand-unexpand" function using JQuery. When user click expand, than the child of the div appear. And when the user click unexpand, the child of the div disappear. But it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.expand').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $(this).html("-");
    $(this).attr("class", "unexpand");

    $.post("classes/ajax_laporan.php",
            {
                id: id
            },
            function(data){
            }
    );
});

$('.unexpand').click(function(){
   $(this).html("+");
   $(this).attr("class", "expand");
});
})
```

Is there anyone can help me solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't uses the addClass and removeClass methods in your program. Refer  http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/ and  http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to use delegation like below because element with `class=unexpand` doesn't exist when DOM is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('click', '.expand', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).html("-");
        $(this).attr("class", "unexpand");
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.unexpand', function () {
        $(this).html("+");
        $(this).attr("class", "expand");
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/AM2JM/)

Comment: When I want to accept, It shows warning that I should wait for 4 min to accept an answer, so please wait. Thank you so much for your help :D